# How do I disable email notifications for Firebase App Distribution

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-beta, fabric-beta, firebase-app-distribution

I have just tried switching from Fabric/Crashlytics Beta to Firebase App Distribution for distributing my Android app to testers. I do so using the Gradle plugin as described here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle

When using Crashlytics Beta, I could disable the annoying emails to testers for every new build by adding this to my gradle file:

```
ext.betaDistributionNotifications=false
```

The docs for Firebase app distribution don't mention anything similar, despite having equivalents for the other options such as release notes. Indeed, the doc says:

> Testers who haven't been invited to test the app receive email invitations to get started. Existing testers receive email notifications that a new build is ready to test.

Does anyone know how I can disable the emails so that I don't constantly spam my testers when I push out builds several times a day?

Edit: Individual testers can use the unsubscribe link at the bottom of the emails, but I'd prefer to disable the emails globally so that this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 9):

This is Zubair from Fabric/Firebase support. @danwilkie - Thanks for the great feedback! and using the Firebase App Distribution. Currently Firebase App Distribution does not support this, but it's good to know you'd love to see this added in. I will forward this request in favor of building it in firebase.  Feel free to reach out us AT 'support@fabric.io', if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi @Zubair, is this feature added yet? I couldn't find it in Firebase app distribution

Comment: @Zubair is there an update on this or someplace I can follow the bug. It's been two years since the issue was raised.

Comment: I'm also waiting for this feature to be added. We have nightly builds and we don't want to spam our testers for those

Comment: Same here, I had to told all testers to put these notifications into filtered box onto their mail, because we use custom notification for it anyway. It's a shame that google/firebase can't enable this simple option

Comment: 4 years and still not possible? As a tester I can tell you these blasted emails are a total pain. Firebase app should have a "notify me" option already.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not specify the tester group or any emails in your Gradle file. For example:

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
            releaseNotesFile="/path/to/releasenotes.txt"
           //Comment out or delete the following line to stop automatically 
           //sending emails to your testers
            testers="ali@example.com, bri@example.com, cal@example.com"
        }
```

We have the same setup for continuous dev/QA builds. I've tested this and it works. You can still add them manually from the Firebase console whenever you want.

Comment: This doesn't work for groups I find. They still get sent the emails.